# Delete row from ng-bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have successfully implemented ng-bootstrap table complete example.
Object deletion from DOM and database are working, but I can't find a way to delete row from view. In order to see the changes page reload is required. Please notice, that delete function is and should be triggered, from ng-bootstrap modal dialog confirm button.

I can't call `data$` from the `for` loop like in the bellow approach or similar ones, because `todo`(or what ever) is observable `todos$`,

```html
<!-- html -->
<tr *ngFor="let todo of tableService.todos$ | async;">
```

```
// typescript
deleteRow(id){
  for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; ++i){
    if (this.data[i].id === id) {
        this.data.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone point me to the right direction, please.

I have this chunk of code:

```
deleteTodo(id: string) {
  this.todoService.deleteTodo(id)
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data); // print message from server
    },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
  this.tableService.todoArray = this.tableService.todoArray.filter(elem => elem._id !== id);
  this.todoLength--;
  this.modalService.dismissAll();
  console.log('filtered array: ' + this.tableService.todoArray.length);
  console.log('id: ' + id);
}
```

This function deletes todo item from database and filter method deletes todo from an array. Please look at the screenshot bellow.

[image]

repo to my app source code:
https://github.com/SrdjanMilic/NG-Bootstrap-Todo-list

Comment: `document.getElementById(id).remove()` might work

Comment: the advice above could lead to unpredictable problems. don't change DOM manually when using Angular unless you 100% sure you how to deal with Angular rendering and change detection

Comment: it's about the time to choose a correct answer (:

Comment: There is no correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that works:

`todo-list.component.ts`

```
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {
  todos$: Observable<Todo[]>;
  total$: Observable<number>;

  @ViewChildren(NgbdSortableHeader) headers: QueryList<NgbdSortableHeader>;

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService, private router: Router, private modalService: NgbModal,
              public tableService: TableService, public updateTodoComponent: UpdateTodoComponent,
              public myBootstrapModalCoomponent: MyBootstrapModalComponent, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.todos$ = this.tableService.todos$;
    this.total$ = this.tableService.total$;
  }

...

deleteTodo(id: string) {
  this.todoService.deleteTodo(id)
    .subscribe(todo => {
      console.log(todo); // print message from server
    },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  this.todos$.subscribe(todos => {
    for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
      if (todos[i]._id === id) {
        todos.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  });
  this.tableService.todoArray.length--;
  this.modalService.dismissAll();
}
```

`table.service.ts`

```
...
private _todos$ = new BehaviorSubject<Todo[]>([]);

get todos$() {
  return this._todos$.asObservable();
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular change detection doesn't work for `splice` because it does not change the reference to the array variable. You need either to update the variable reference (example below) or [trigger change detection manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-change-detection-manually-in-angular).

```
deleteRow(id) {
   this.data = this.data.filter(elem => elem.id !== id);
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at edited question, I have added more info...  I have tried `this.tableService.todoArray.filter(el => el._id !== id);` somewhere in deleteTodo() but nothing has happen. Maybe I wrote it wrong, or something else is missing. It seems to me really weird. Thank you very much for taking your time.

Comment: I don't have access to your repo. stabblitz usually easy to use in such cases. have you tried this one?
this.tableService.todoArray = this.tableService.todoArray.filter(el => el._id !== id);

Comment: I'm really sorry. I forgot to change access from private to public. There is a bunch of components in the project, so I find time consuming to copy them all to stackblitz. Also, there is a node server as well. Anyway, please take a look at repo now. P.S. I have tried above with no luck. If this is meaningful, the ng-bootstrap api use some method to **refresh** the table. It can be triggered from the search input field. When it's triggered, the row vanish and there is no need to refresh the page.

Comment: This solution doesn't work at all. Something else is not right here.

Comment: it would be nice to be able to reproduce the issue. most likely smg else leads to such a bug